# Multiple runs on docx4j generate unexpected results

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I have an application which consists of a simple html page with a text input. This text input relates to a database identifier, in order to fill some templates.

The document I'm filling is only a page, with a title, and a table with data, populated with the data obtained from the query with the identifier.

It works properly for the first document I ellaborate, but the second one does not: on the second and consecutive runs, the table just disappears.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
            .load(new File(inputFile));
VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
/* I ellaborate a HashMap<String, String> called mappings from the results
obtained from the database here */
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().variableReplace(mappings);
wordMLPackage.save(new File(outputFile));
```

inputFile and outputFile are simple strings containing the paths to the files.

I found out several "winword.exe" processes run simultaneously, and they do not shut down when the execution ends. In addition, I keep getting a popup saying that "normal.dotm" has changed and prompts me to save the changes. Could this be related?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would need to see your docx. If it worked 10 times, it might be https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/164

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @JasonPlutext. Here's a link to the file:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=89513650763841168756

Comment: Alright! Managed to solve it, thanks @JasonPlutext. I just changed the version to the most recent one and everything worked just fine. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes, looking at the document, the table was in mc:AlternateContent which points to that issue.